# AWS S3 redirect https to a new domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

So I am changing the domain for my website to another. Because some users might have it bookmarked I need to redirect from old domain to new domain. They all use https.
I tried creating a S3 bucket in Amazon and Route 53 to redirect (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/) and it works fine for my old domain in http, however my server has a redirect rule from http to https so must likely users have bookmarked the https address.

In this case, 
http://olddomain.com redirects fine to https://newdomain.com
but 
https://olddomain.com presents an error (it doesn't load, "This site can’t be reached").

I looked through the AWS documentation and it says that S3 can't redirect from https. 
Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I solved it by creating a S3 bucket with the old domain and redirection. Then associating that with a  Distribution at CloudFront to redirect to https and finally in route53 assigning the alias to the distribution. so the distribution will take care of the https redirection and the s3 to the actual domain redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing a bucket redirect, create a CNAME or Alias record in your old domain DNS records which points to your new domain.

See here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html